# Why does memcpy use prefetcht0 of the 4 cosecutive cache lines?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, memcpy, avx

I'm analyzing implementation of `memcpy` which is on my machine Kaby Lake i7 goes down to `__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms`. The `__x86_shared_non_temporal_threshold` that is used to determine if AVX Non-Temporal stores should be used is 6 MiB on my machine. The code fragment for non temporals is this:

```
0x000000000018ee21 <+849>: prefetcht0 -0x100(%rcx)
prefetcht0 -0x140(%rcx)
prefetcht0 -0x180(%rcx)
prefetcht0 -0x1c0(%rcx)
vmovdqu (%rcx),%ymm0
vmovdqu -0x20(%rcx),%ymm1
vmovdqu -0x40(%rcx),%ymm2
vmovdqu -0x60(%rcx),%ymm3
sub    $0x80,%rcx
sub    $0x80,%rdx
vmovntdq %ymm0,(%r9)
vmovntdq %ymm1,-0x20(%r9)
vmovntdq %ymm2,-0x40(%r9)
vmovntdq %ymm3,-0x60(%r9)
sub    r9,0x80
cmp    rdx,0x80
ja     0x18ee21 <__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms+849>
```

**QUESTION:** Is `prefetcht0` really useful? We have HW prefetch already so the absence of SW prefetches should not cause much difference.

---

I wrote my own copy function to measure performance difference with and without `prefetcht0`. For simplicity I assumed that the source and destination are page aligned and their size is multiple to page size (this is most likely to be true for I/O).

There are 2 implementations:

**I.** `avx_copy_unr15` with no SW prefetch

Declaration:

```
void *avx_copy_unr15(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t sz);
```

Implementation:

```
//rdi - dest
//rsi - src
//rdx - size
avx_copy_unr15:
cmp $0, %rdx
jz avx_copy_unr15_ret
avx_copy_unr15_loop:
vmovapd (%rsi), %ymm0
vmovapd 0x20(%rsi), %ymm1
vmovapd 0x40(%rsi), %ymm2
vmovapd 0x60(%rsi), %ymm3
vmovapd 0x80(%rsi), %ymm4
vmovapd 0xA0(%rsi), %ymm5
vmovapd 0xC0(%rsi), %ymm6
vmovapd 0xE0(%rsi), %ymm7
vmovapd 0x100(%rsi), %ymm8
vmovapd 0x120(%rsi), %ymm9
vmovapd 0x140(%rsi), %ymm10
vmovapd 0x160(%rsi), %ymm11
vmovapd 0x180(%rsi), %ymm12
vmovapd 0x1A0(%rsi), %ymm13
vmovapd 0x1C0(%rsi), %ymm14
vmovapd 0x1E0(%rsi), %ymm15
vmovntpd %ymm0, (%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm1, 0x20(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm2, 0x40(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm3, 0x60(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm4, 0x80(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm5, 0xA0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm6, 0xC0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm7, 0xE0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm8, 0x100(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm9, 0x120(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm10, 0x140(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm11, 0x160(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm12, 0x180(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm13, 0x1A0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm14, 0x1C0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm15, 0x1E0(%rdi)
add $0x200, %rsi
add $0x200, %rdi
sub $0x200, %rdx
jnz avx_copy_unr15_loop
avx_copy_unr15_ret:
vzeroupper
ret
```

**II.** `avx_copy_unr15_sw_prefetch` with SW prefetch

Declaration:

```
void *avx_copy_unr15_sw_prefetch(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t sz);
```

Implementation (according to @Jester comment I changed `prefetcht0` for the next iteration):

```
//rdi - dest
//rsi - src
//rdx - size
avx_copy_unr15_sw_prefetch:
cmp $0, %rdx
jz avx_copy_unr15_ret
avx_copy_unr15_loop:
prefetcht0 0x200(%rsi)
prefetcht0 0x240(%rsi)
prefetcht0 0x280(%rsi)
prefetcht0 0x2C0(%rsi)
prefetcht0 0x300(%rsi)
prefetcht0 0x340(%rsi)
prefetcht0 0x380(%rsi)
prefetcht0 0x3C0(%rsi)
vmovapd (%rsi), %ymm0
vmovapd 0x20(%rsi), %ymm1
vmovapd 0x40(%rsi), %ymm2
vmovapd 0x60(%rsi), %ymm3
vmovapd 0x80(%rsi), %ymm4
vmovapd 0xA0(%rsi), %ymm5
vmovapd 0xC0(%rsi), %ymm6
vmovapd 0xE0(%rsi), %ymm7
vmovapd 0x100(%rsi), %ymm8
vmovapd 0x120(%rsi), %ymm9
vmovapd 0x140(%rsi), %ymm10
vmovapd 0x160(%rsi), %ymm11
vmovapd 0x180(%rsi), %ymm12
vmovapd 0x1A0(%rsi), %ymm13
vmovapd 0x1C0(%rsi), %ymm14
vmovapd 0x1E0(%rsi), %ymm15
vmovntpd %ymm0, (%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm1, 0x20(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm2, 0x40(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm3, 0x60(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm4, 0x80(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm5, 0xA0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm6, 0xC0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm7, 0xE0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm8, 0x100(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm9, 0x120(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm10, 0x140(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm11, 0x160(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm12, 0x180(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm13, 0x1A0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm14, 0x1C0(%rdi)
vmovntpd %ymm15, 0x1E0(%rdi)
add $0x200, %rsi
add $0x200, %rdi
sub $0x200, %rdx
jnz avx_copy_unr15_loop
avx_copy_unr15_ret:
vzeroupper
ret
```

I measured this using `__rdtsc()` intrinsic available in `x86intrin.h` and on about 10 measurement runs I did about 20000 iterations and noticed that the SW prefetch is just about `1`-`1.5`% faster.

Is it a measurement error or SW prefetch really helps? Here is how 1 iteration of my measurement looks like:

```
#define DO_MEASURE(fn, iterations_total, ...) \
    __extension__({\
        uint64_t total_tsc = 0; \
        unsigned total = iterations_total; \
        while(total --> 0) { \
            uint64_t start = __rdtsc(); \
            fn(__VA_ARGS__); \
            fn(__VA_ARGS__); \
            fn(__VA_ARGS__); \
            fn(__VA_ARGS__); \
            fn(__VA_ARGS__); \
            fn(__VA_ARGS__); \
            fn(__VA_ARGS__); \
            fn(__VA_ARGS__); \
            uint64_t finish = __rdtsc(); \
            uint64_t iteration_result = (finish - start) / 8; \
            total_tsc += iteration_result; \
        }; \
        total_tsc / iterations_total; \
    })
```

---

Here is how the whole source file for measurement looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "memcp.h" //header with asm("") implementation
#include "benchmark.h" //header with DO_MEASURE macro shown above

#define BUF_SIZE 4096 * 1024
#define ITERATIONS 2000

_Alignas(4096) char src[BUF_SIZE];
_Alignas(4096) char dest[BUF_SIZE];

int main(void){
    int fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, src, BUF_SIZE);

    unsigned avx_unr15_iterations_total = 10;
    unsigned avx_unr15_iteration = 0;
    while(avx_unr15_iteration++ < avx_unr15_iterations_total){
        unsigned long result = DO_MEASURE(avx_copy_unr15, ITERATIONS, dest, src, BUF_SIZE);
        printf("avx_copy_unr15: iteration %u = %lu\n", avx_unr15_iteration, result);
    }

    unsigned avx_unr15_sw_prefetch_iterations_total = 10;
    unsigned avx_unr15_sw_prefetch_iteration = 0;
    while(avx_unr15_sw_prefetch_iteration++ < avx_unr15_sw_prefetch_iterations_total){
        unsigned long result = DO_MEASURE(avx_copy_unr15_sw_prefetch, ITERATIONS, dest, src, BUF_SIZE);
        printf("avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration %u = %lu\n", avx_unr15_sw_prefetch_iteration, result);
    }
}
```

Compiling this with `-Werror -Wextra -pedantic -Wall -g3 -O3 -Wno-unused-result` The result of running such benchmarks is this:

```
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 1 = 296576
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 2 = 289416
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 3 = 287765
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 4 = 287584
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 5 = 287525
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 6 = 290479
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 7 = 286566
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 8 = 287082
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 9 = 287584
avx_copy_unr15: iteration 10 = 288825

avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 1 = 288732
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 2 = 287374
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 3 = 286325
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 4 = 287374
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 5 = 297077
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 6 = 323929
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 7 = 321866
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 8 = 321503
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 9 = 321280
avx_copy_sw_prefetch_unr15: iteration 10 = 329869
```

Taking `perf record` on sw prefetch version shows the following results:

```
 18,19 │  0:   prefetcht0 0x200(%rsi)                                                                                                                                                                              
  9,89 │       prefetcht0 0x240(%rsi)                                                                                                                                                                              
  8,85 │       prefetcht0 0x280(%rsi)                                                                                                                                                                              
  7,95 │       prefetcht0 0x2c0(%rsi)                                                                                                                                                                              
  7,02 │       prefetcht0 0x300(%rsi)                                                                                                                                                                              
  6,20 │       prefetcht0 0x340(%rsi)                                                                                                                                                                              
  5,58 │       prefetcht0 0x380(%rsi)                                                                                                                                                                              
  4,99 │       prefetcht0 0x3c0(%rsi)                                                                                                                                                                              
  1,42 │       vmovapd (%rsi),%ymm0                                                                                                                                                                                
  0,42 │       vmovapd 0x20(%rsi),%ymm1                                                                                                                                                                            
  1,44 │       vmovapd 0x40(%rsi),%ymm2                                                                                                                                                                            
  0,60 │       vmovapd 0x60(%rsi),%ymm3                                                                                                                                                                            
  1,22 │       vmovapd 0x80(%rsi),%ymm4                                                                                                                                                                            
  0,42 │       vmovapd 0xa0(%rsi),%ymm5                                                                                                                                                                            
  1,40 │       vmovapd 0xc0(%rsi),%ymm6                                                                                                                                                                            
  0,63 │       vmovapd 0xe0(%rsi),%ymm7                                                                                                                                                                            
  1,42 │       vmovapd 0x100(%rsi),%ymm8                                                                                                                                                                           
  0,47 │       vmovapd 0x120(%rsi),%ymm9                                                                                                                                                                           
  1,43 │       vmovapd 0x140(%rsi),%ymm10                                                                                                                                                                          
  0,61 │       vmovapd 0x160(%rsi),%ymm11                                                                                                                                                                          
  1,25 │       vmovapd 0x180(%rsi),%ymm12                                                                                                                                                                          
  0,47 │       vmovapd 0x1a0(%rsi),%ymm13                                                                                                                                                                          
  1,42 │       vmovapd 0x1c0(%rsi),%ymm14                                                                                                                                                                          
  0,67 │       vmovapd 0x1e0(%rsi),%ymm15                                                                                                                                                                          
  2,40 │       vmovntpd %ymm0,(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                               
  0,95 │       vmovntpd %ymm1,0x20(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                           
  0,79 │       vmovntpd %ymm2,0x40(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                           
  0,90 │       vmovntpd %ymm3,0x60(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                           
  0,77 │       vmovntpd %ymm4,0x80(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                           
  0,85 │       vmovntpd %ymm5,0xa0(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                           
  0,92 │       vmovntpd %ymm6,0xc0(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                           
  1,00 │       vmovntpd %ymm7,0xe0(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                           
  0,78 │       vmovntpd %ymm8,0x100(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                          
  0,86 │       vmovntpd %ymm9,0x120(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                          
  0,90 │       vmovntpd %ymm10,0x140(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                         
  1,09 │       vmovntpd %ymm11,0x160(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                         
  0,84 │       vmovntpd %ymm12,0x180(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                         
  0,74 │       vmovntpd %ymm13,0x1a0(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                         
  0,64 │       vmovntpd %ymm14,0x1c0(%rdi)                                                                                                                                                                         
  0,70 │       vmovntpd %ymm15,0x1e0(%rdi)
```

Comment: You may like to interleave loads and stores when not doing software prefetching to let the hardware prefetcher know your intent earlier. E.g. store `ymm0`, load next `ymm0`, store `ymm1`, load next `ymm1`...

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Not really got your point about interleave. Stores cannot be reordered with earlier loads which is the case here. Or could you please expand?

Comment: The main intent is to initiate the load earlier. That serves the same purpose as `prefetcht0`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I tried to measure with and without SW prefetch and did not get  significant difference on my machine. 1-1.5% which is probably measurement error...

Comment: Note that the first version prefetches for the **next** iteration, not the current one. Also that's copying backwards which might be worse for the hw prefetching.

Comment: @Jester Good point! I tried to also prefetch data from the next iteration, but it did not get any differences in terms of `rdtsc`. I need to examine perf counters in case I missed something.

Comment: Good question, but a lot of information is missing. Show the absolute numbers for your measurements. How are the buffers allocated and initialized? What's the size of the buffers? What is you compiler, compilation options, runtime library version? Show the whole loop of `__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms`. Regarding your last comment, it's important to show the numbers and the code.

Comment: @HadiBrais I added the whole benchmark program source code with the results and all other details.

Comment: @Jester You were right. I read Intel Optimization Manual, `Section 3.7.2` about hardware prefetches and there were the following rule to have benefits from prefetchers: _Access the data in increasing addresses, in sequential cache lines._

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin's first comment was about "interleaving" is talking about software pipelining and moving each store as late as possible (right before the load that reloads it) which might help hide some load latency.  Or not, or it might hurt for other reasons.  You generally want the NT stores for a single cache line to be done back to back to minimize the chance of a partially-full LFB (WC buffer) being evicted / flushed.

Comment: Even doing NT stores out of order (in the source) can be quite harmful: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69622 / [Wrong gcc generated assembly ordering, results in performance hit](//stackoverflow.com/q/25778302).

Comment: @Jester: There are a few different HW prefetchers on mainstream Intel HW (non-Atom).  The most important one is the L2 streamer which can track 1 forward and 1 backward stream per 4k page [prefetching data at L1 and L2](//stackoverflow.com/q/20544917).  Also related: an attempt to measure it ([Xeon CPU (E5-2603) backward memory prefetch](//stackoverflow.com/q/51933660)) but it tries to time single accesses and uses a lot of fences; pretty different from measuring sequential read, write or copy bandwidth with timing outside the loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes Is there a way to understand which prefetcher kicks int DCU/IP;Spatial/Streamer and how many lines were prefetched in total during execution of some code? Maybe some `perf counters` or `MSR`s? Also Intel Core mentioned `DPL` which is to prefetch data into L2 based on how `DCU` accesses data. Is it related to the L2 prefetchers or stays aside of them?

Comment: @PeterCordes It seems it is not possible to switch off HW prefetching on Kaby Lake and Coffee Lake to compare the performance with and without it. There is no such `MSR` availbale for those architectures.

Comment: You could try setting the memory range to uncacheable.

Comment: I think the different prefetchers are basically independent.  Note that "DCU" is Intel's term for L1d cache.  I should have mentioned earlier that at least one of the prefetchers, maybe DCU (L1d) doesn't do as well with backward accesses, maybe not triggering at all.  That might not be a problem for memcpy where letting OoO exec hide L2 hit latency is ok.  Yes there are some perf counters for prefetchers, use `perf stat`. Or google for more about how to investigate prefetching. I'd be surprised of there's really no MSR for disabling HW prefetch on KBL / CFL; maybe different from earlier though

Comment: @PeterCordes I ran some benchmarks with backward access and noticed 50% `L1d-cache misses` without SW prefetches. Adding just one SW `prefetcht0` a few cache lines backward reduced L1d misses from 50% to 33% improving performance averagely by `10%`. So to recap the `prefetcht0` in the `__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms` implemention was to improve efficiency  of using L1d cache. As per Intel Optimization Manual `L2-streamer` can do with backward access as well and is not suffering from performance degradation cause by backward access.